# SQL server slow select query from type varbinary(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table which one of the columns with type [Data] (varbinary(max), not null).
I saved one row, and I checked the size of the image size:

```
SELECT SUM(Datalength(Data)) FROM t_photo where id=2256 => 355249
```

When I execute the query:

```
select data from t_photo where id=2256
```

It takes about ~10 seconds

What can I do to lower this query time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was not to save the byte array of the image in th DB, but to store the image in the blob storage, and save in the db only the URL of this image

Answer (score 2):

Index the table on `id`. If that still takes more than a fraction of a second there might be blocking involved or extreme amounts of IO. Run `sp_whoisactive` to see what it is.

Comment: Mi Id column is already the PK, so Index won't work here. Query of byte array with length ~400,000 supposed to take 10 seconds? Or maybe something is wrong with the way I save the image - image size 400x400 - what should be its size in byte array?