# Minimizing select time in Varbinary(max) column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am facing a issue with latency when I select images which are saved in a `varbinary(max)` column in SQL Server, it takes around 3-5 mins to select at least 5 images. This table (`galleryDetail`) contains images with different sizes like 2mb, 40kb, 1mb likewise. As suggested in this link [SQL server slow select query from type varbinary(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441073/sql-server-slow-select-query-from-type-varbinarymax/32807586#32807586) (last comment),if somebody could give me a road map/suggestion, to achieve this task, it  would be a big Help.

My table structure is as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GalleryDetail]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Image] [VARBINARY](MAX) NULL,
    [Title] [VARCHAR](250) NULL,
    [Active] [BIT] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [DATETIME] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ImageGallery] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GalleryDetail] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_GalleryDetail_Active] DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
GO
```

Comment: It takes 3-5 minutes to select. I need more detail please, the code would be best.  My main curiosity is if this is the transfer time, or the actual select time as stated.

Comment: Right, are we talking `SELECT`, or are we talking end-to-end, `SELECT, transfer, render, download, etc.`?

Comment: How do you select from this table? By Id? If you select by other column (e.g. by [Title]) then an index on that column may help.

Comment: @Trey : its just the select SQL statement - select * from GalleryDetail, its the actual select Query execution time took 3-5 minutes

Comment: @vadim: I actually select the image by Title, depends on the title of the image images load like images in a gallery

Answer (score 0):

If you select by Title column then add index to make select faster:

```
create index idx_Title on dbo.GalleryDetail(Title)
```

This only helps if Title is in the where clause of your query, e.g.

```
select * from GalleryDetail where Title = 'My picture'
```

or

```
select * from GalleryDetail where Title like 'picture%'
```

Comment: thank you. it definitely  reduced around 5 to 6 seconds.and what else i can do to enhance the speed.hence can you brief the indexing that of what you have commented.